# jQuery callback not firing when declaring complete:?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-animate, jquery-callback

I have an animation to remove content from the screen by scaling the opacity down to 0. I then want to set the css property of visibility to hidden. In order to get the sequence correct, I have been trying to use an alert box to know when the event triggers. The alert box does not show. Here is my code:

```
                $('.save-hidden').animate({
                    opacity: 0, 
                    complete: function() { alert('Executes now.');}
                }, 2000);
```

Is my syntax correct for calling the function? As I said, the alert never displays.

I intend to replace it with the following call:

```
                $('.save-hidden').css({ visibility: "visible"});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `animate()` supports two different types of syntax, the first one being

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

which you would use this way

```
$('.save-hidden').animate({opacity: 0}, 2000, function() { 
    alert('Executes now.');}
});
```

The second syntax, which looks like the one you're trying to use, would be

```
.animate( properties, options )
```

Here you could use two objects, the first one containing the properties to animate, and the second one containing the options, like `complete()` etc.

In other words, the `complete` callback does not belong in the object with the properties to animate, but one can add another object as the second argument, containing properties like `duration`, `complete`, `queue` etc.
Note that this syntax would have all callbacks, easings etc. in the options object, and only accept two arguments.

```
$('.save-hidden').animate({
    opacity: 0
}, {
    complete: function() { 
        alert('Executes now.');
    },
    duration : 2000
});
```

Comment: Using your syntax, the alert seems to work but the setting in css does not. Is there anything I have to change to make this work? Updated code:          $('.save-hidden').animate(
     {opacity: 0},
     {
      complete: { function() {$('.save-hidden').css({ visibility: "hidden"});} },
      duration: 2000
     }
    );

Comment: I got it, i had not followed your structure as defined above. Many thanks!